# How can I customise 'matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, patch

Hot can I create a customised matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ArrowStyle

plt.figure(1, figsize=(9,9))

ArrowStyle("Test", head_length=.4, head_width=200, tail_width=2)

ax = plt.subplot(111)

ax.annotate("",
            xy=(0.2, 0.2), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(0.8, 0.8), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="Test",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"), 
            )

plt.show()
```

[image: ?]

I would like to change the width of the head and the tail. In the [matplotlib documentation on matplotlib.patches.arrowstyle](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html) it is written, that an arrowstyle object can be created as `ArrowStyle("Fancy", head_length=.4, head_width=.4, tail_width=.4)`. However, when I change the parameters, the style of the arrow remains the same.

Comment: `ArrowStyle` is a class in `matplotlib.patches`. Did you import it correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well, I used the code above and I suppose I didn't import it correctly. However, I now introduced `from matplotlib.patches import ArrowStyle` and `ArrowStyle("test", head_length=.4, head_width=2, tail_width=.4)`. i now get `ValueError: Unknown style : test`.

Comment: Ah ok,apaprently I have to stick to the predefined styles. Anyway, changing the parameters head_width and so on does not affect the look. I'll update my question.

Comment: Of course you need to ***use*** the `ArrowStyle` in your `annotate` function. Just placing it on top of the script will not change anything.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. But I am using it, or not? `arrowstyle="Fancy"`

Comment: No, You just create the `ArrowStyle` object in line 4 of the code and in line 5 it's already removed from memory because you don't assign it to a variable. Especially, how should `annotate` know that you want to use that object?

Comment: Ok, that's a bit of Chinese for me. I tried `ax.ArrowStyle("Fancy", head_length=.4, head_width=200, tail_width=2)` after `plt.figure()` but that won't work either.

Comment: Currently you use `arrowstyle="Fancy"`. But now you want to use a different arrowstyle. So instead of `"Fancy"` you need to supply that new arrowstyle.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That's what I am doing or not (see my 2nd comment). I also updated the code in my question.

Comment: `"Test"` is no valid name for an arrow style. I'm giving up here.